# How to configure HikariCP with EclipseLink JPA

Tags: eclipselink, hikaricp

I am upgrading my (old) application (JSF/Java) that uses HikariCP as its connection provider. Now I would like to use JPA and EclipseLink. Any suggestions on how to use HikariCP with EclipseLink?

On the HikariCP, there is only a configuration for Hibernate: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Hibernate4

How could I do the same in EclipseLink?

Comment: any suggestions?